# How to remove the blur on matplotlib candlestick sticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

Any idea about how to remove the blur on matplotlib candlestick sticks? They seem to have a blur/haze to them (or I need glasses).

Here's a screenshot of mine:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of a non blurred example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the graphic you show is produced using the inline backend in a IPython QT or Jupyter notebook. It could also orginiate from a saved pdf file. 
In any case it seems that there is no antialiasing used.

You can turn antialiasing off manually for the candlestick patches

```
lines, patches = candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.5)
for patch in patches:
    patch.set_edgecolor("k")
    patch.set_antialiased(False)
```

or globally for all patches

```
plt.rcParams["patch.antialiased"] = False
```

In order to obtain a result similar to the one in the shown figure you may also want to set the line width to 0.72 (such that lines are 1 pixel thick, or to be precise to 72./fig.dpi if dpi is not 100).

Using

```
lines, patches = candlestick_ohlc(ax, quotes, width=0.5)
for patch in patches:
    patch.set_edgecolor("k")
    patch.set_linewidth(0.72)
    patch.set_antialiased(False)
```

the result from the [candlestick example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/finance_demo.html) looks much like in the picture from the question.

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I need to figure out how to color the candle wicks black now too. FYI: the graph was produced from a python/matlibplot script I wrote and opened with Terminal.